# Direct Proxy without parameter

Tags: jquery

I can't proxy the function a without wrapping into a function:

```
function a(b) {
  if (arguments.length != 0){
    throw 'illegal';
  }
  alert(this);
}


jQuery.proxy(a,"Great!");  /// throw error because b is an event.
jQuery.proxy(a,"Great!",undefined); // throw error because length is 1
jQuery.proxy(function(){a();},"Great!"); // ok, but not directly.
```

I can't change the function a!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to make a bound function but stripping arguments.

Then the `$.proxy` wrapping isn't the simpler solution. You may do it with only one wrapping like this :

```
function() { a.call("Great!") }
```

Comment: this is not directly and wrapped into a function ... i will wait for better answers.

Comment: $.proxy wraps too. What I achieve is one wrapping instead of many (and it's shorter, too).

Comment: yes it wrapps too, but in case of `.one({click:$.proxy(...), ...});` it wrapps one time fewer.

Comment: You don't seem to have understood. $.proxy wraps too. So I propose to replace `.one({click:$.proxy(...), ...});` with `.one({click:function() { a.call("Great!") }, ...});`.

Comment: oh ok, im skeptic why they founded the .proxy()-method then. Are there no benefits i might miss?

Comment: It's convenient when you don't have `bind` because you want to be compatible with IE8. Now, it's slowly becoming more and more irrelevant.